# How to access authenticated user from a Service Provider class?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to access the currently authenticated user from a custom service provider class like this

```
public function register()
{
    if (auth()->user()->SOME_CONDITION()) {
        app()->bind('App\Repositories\SomeRepositoryInterface', "App\Repositories\SomeRepository");
    }
}
```

but it is not possible and getting the below error..

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class
> [hash] does not exist.

ّI'm trying to apply dependency injection and DYNAMICALLY bind interfaces to implementations depending on the authenticated user type , but cannot do it because it is not possible access / retrieve authenticated user from service provider classes, also if i tried to do the binding from a middleware instead, not possible because the controllers constructors get called / executed before the middleware..

Is there a workaround or a better way for this ?

Comment: if you are using session based auth, you won't have access to the session until after the `StartSession` middleware has ran, which is way way after the service providers register their bindings ... also you can't be calling things that also rely on bindings in the `register` method as they may not have been registered yet: like the `hash` binding or `auth` itself

Comment: @lagbox 

Thanks for help 
I tried achieving this using a middleware but not possible either

Comment: well it is possible as you can add bindings at any time after the providers have registered theirs, so you will have to elaborate on why its not possible in your situation

Comment: @lagbox 
says the class is not instantiable which means the middleware is not taking effect as if the middleware is not executed for some reason..

Comment: you can't be trying to resolve this interface before your middleware gets the chance to run then ... you are not really providing much information here

Comment: well, i added the code in the AuthServiceProvider instead of my custom provider and it worked.. 
any chance to get it working from my custom service provider class ?

Comment: @lagbox

The AuthServiceProvider try was unsuccessful as the auth()->check() is always returning false, the middleware method is not working because the controller constructor is called before the middleware.. so m getting error 
Target [App\Repositories\Admin\AdminRepositoryInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it by using a middleware inside the controller constructor PLUS using `app()->make()` function for binding like below:-

```
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            if(auth()->user()->is_admin_user) {
                $class = 'App\ClassA';
            }
            else {
                $class = 'App\ClassB';
            }
            $this->adminRepository = app()->make($class);
        return $next($request);
    });
```